# HomeState not defined for Home | Already defined?

Tags: flutter

I am building a bottom navigation, and I am getting the error that

`HomeState isn't defined for the type 'Home'`

However, am I not already defining it in the block of code where this error is being thrown?

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}
```

Here is the full block of code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:App/Camera.dart';
import 'package:App/Settings.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
// properties

  int currentTab = 0;
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    Settings(),
    Camera(),
    Home(),
  ];

  Widget currentScreen = Home();

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageStorage(
        child: currentScreen,
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.camera),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            child: Row(children: <Widget>[
              Row(children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(
                  minWidth: 60,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        currentScreen = Home();
                        currentTab = 0;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.message,
                          color: currentTab == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ]),
                )
              ]),
              Row(children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(
                  minWidth: 60,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        currentScreen = Settings();
                        currentTab = 1;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.message,
                          color: currentTab == 1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ]),
                )
              ])
            ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing underscore.

It should be:

```
@override
_HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
```

instead of

```
@override
_HomeState createState() => HomeState();
```